# Rails 5 Assignment of _ids array fails on has_many: through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When upgrading from Rails 3.2 to Rails 5 I ran into this problem where a model suddenly refuses to save.

I have 2 models: `ClosingDay` and `Location` which have a has_many :through relation via a `ClosingDayLocation` model. When creating a `ClosingDay` the user needs to select 1 or more `Location` records using checkboxes.

However, regardless of which `Location` records I select on the form, I always get an error saving the `ClosingDay` record telling me that the associated `ClosingDayLocation` is invalid because `closing_day_id` is empty.

**Models:**

```
class ClosingDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :closing_day_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :locations, :through => :closing_day_locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :closing_day_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :closing_days, :through => :closing_day_locations
end

class ClosingDayLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :closing_day

  validates :closing_day_id, :presence => true
  validates :location_id, :presence => true
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def create
    @closing_day = ClosingDay.build(closing_day_params)

    if @closing_day.save
      redirect_to(closing_days_url, :notice => 'OK')
    else
      @locations = Location.active.order(:name)
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def closing_day_params
    params.require(:closing_day).permit(:date, :name, location_ids: [])
  end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(@closing_day) do |f| %>
    <%= show_errors_for(@closing_day) %>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :name %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.label :date %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :date %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><%= label_tag 'closing_day[location_ids][]', 'Locations' %></td>
        <td>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'closing_day[location_ids][]', nil %>
          <% @locations.each do |location| %>
              <p>
                <%= label_tag do %>
                    <%= check_box_tag 'closing_day[location_ids][]', location.id, @closing_day.location_ids.include?(location.id) %>
                    <%= location.name %>
                <% end %>
              </p>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><%= f.submit %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

So in short, I want to create a new `@closing_day` record and assign associated (pre-existing) locations by assigning `Location` IDs using `@closing_day.location_ids = [3,6,9]` essentially. This works in Rails 3.2 but does not seem to work in Rails 5.

What is the best way to still keep this functionality? I have also tried adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :closing_day_locations, :allow_destroy => true` but that does not seem to work. The associated `ClosingDayLocation` models seem to be created, but the `closing_day_id` remains empty, resulting in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more tinkering I found the problem and solved it. I'll share it here in case others run into the same issues!

```
class ClosingDayLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :closing_day

  #validates :closing_day_id, :presence => true
  #validates :location_id, :presence => true
end
```

After removing those 2 validations on the intermediate model it worked fine for both creating and updating. Apparently some ordering in validating and saving associated records has shifted around between Rails 3.2 and Rails 5.

Comment: Also, you said you were using has-and-belongs-to-many but from your code I think you are using has_many : through